# Using different 404 error pages depending on URL tried by the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, web-config, http-status-code-404

(Note: I'm pretty new to asp.net/c#, bear with me please)

On my website i use a custom 404 error page by using this in my web.config

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="http://mywebsite.org/404">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="http://mywebsite.org/404" />
</customErrors>
```

Now I want to add additional 404 pages that are "triggered" by URLs containing certain strings. For example if the URL contains `/library/` I want the user to be redirected to `http://mywebsite.org/library-404` which contains information specific to the library part of the website. Same goes for URLs containing `/services/`, and others.

Can this be done? If so, how? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ASP.NET MVC.Set the Route to map the Url.

Comment: Can you include an example of how to set the routemap to the URL? As it stands this is more of a comment then an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define method Application_Error in *Global.asax.cs* and handle like this

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var error = Server.GetLastError();
    var code = (error is HttpException) ? (error as HttpException).GetHttpCode() : 500;
    string path = Request.Path;

    if (code == 404)
    {
        if (new Regex(@"\/library\/", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(path))
        {
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Library/Error404"));
        }
    }
}
```